# How to change Device Filter via a Editor script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to write a editor script to auto fill the player settings, but don't know how to chose the "Devices Filter".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.Android-targetDevice.html

```
using UnityEditor;
//......
PlayerSettings.Android.targetDevice = AndroidTargetDevice.ARMv7;
```